# NonSerializedAttribute injection with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, serialization, mono.cecil, binaryformatter

I made post build task which uses `Mono.Cecil` to inject `NonSerializedAttribute` on some custom fields for binary serialization. Using `ILSpy` tool i see that attribute is injected, but when i run application, i get `SerializationException` with information that type of that property is not marked as serialiazable, which is correct, but that's why i injected `NonSerializedAttribute`.

Little code illustation:

```
public class NonSerializableType
{
   ....
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableType
{
    private NonSerializableType _data;

    public NonSerializableType Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }
 }
```

After injection i can see `NonSerializedAttribute` on `_data` field (using `ILSpy`) but it's not working at run time. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Did you mark the field as nonserialized, or the property?  In your question you use both "field" and "property".  2) Can you share the code that does the injection?

Comment: Thank you for replay, but i solved issue. Before i did NonSerialized attribute injection, i had another injection task which transformed auto implemented property into full property. So whole process was to inject field for property, and transfrom it to full property (with my field, not compiler backing field), and that on that injected field, add NonSerializedAttribute. For some reason, GetType().GetFields() didn't know about that field, it's like Mono.Cecil injection corrupted reflection and that was the main problem. BinaryFormatter uses reflection to serialize objects.

Comment: Solution was to find field with Mono.Cecil and instead of adding NonSerialized attribute to it's CustomAttributeCollection, just set FieldDefinition.IsNonSerialized to true, which didn't "corrupt" reflection like i said in previous comment.